# The test form is only available for requests from the local machine

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-3.5, asmx

Why is it that for some of my web services, I get test forms, so I can see the generated XML data, but for other web services, I get a message saying *"The test form is only available for requests from the local machine."*?

Both times, I am connecting to the URL of the web-service from a client side browser and all web services are created with C#, .NET 3.5.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["The test form is only available for requests from the local machine."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028010/the-test-form-is-only-available-for-requests-from-the-local-machine)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I googled for ["The test form is only available for requests from the local machine."](https://www.google.com/search?q=The%20test%20form%20is%20only%20available%20for%20requests%20from%20the%20local%20machine.)

There were many results, and the consensus is to add these nodes to the *web.config* file of the web service. I haven't tried this solution yet, but you can check to see if your web services that shows the test form remotely has this that have these nodes in the *web.config*. Or, you can add it to the web services that give this message and see if the test form starts appearing remotely.

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Here are some of the search results

- Stack Overflow: [The test form is only available for requests from the local machine.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028010/the-test-form-is-only-available-for-requests-from-the-local-machine)
- GeeksWithBlogs *(archived on the Internet Wayback Machine)*: ["The test form is only available for requests from the local machine"](https://web.archive.org/web/20201024064831/http://geekswithblogs.net/juang/archive/2005/11/28/61437.aspx)
- Microsoft support: [INFO: HTTP GET and HTTP POST Are Disabled by Default](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819267)

Comment: The third link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to *[Geekswithblogs.net, the End of an Era](http://julian.farm/geekswithblogs/?url=/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx)*.

Comment: Thanks @PeterMortensen!  I updated the link with the archived post on the Internet Wayback Machine (web.archive.org).