# How to publish a Web Service from VS 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, web, raspberry-pi

I have created a Web Service on VS 2012 .
**Now what I want to do is to invoke this Web Service from a Client  but the trick is that the client is running on another computer ( on Raspberry Pi computer and written in Java -- though I think I doesn't matter) .**

When those two programs were on the same machine it worked perfectly but now I want to 
initiate the Client from another computer.

From what I have read I understand that I need to Publish this Web Service on my Computer,
but I haven't fount suitable guide of how to do it (read about IIS -- do I need it ?)?
Moreover do I need to make some changes on my Client so it wont look for a Web Service on
local machine?
The Client was created using WSDL files from the Web Service Server.

Thanks .

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to host the service on your development box and just hit it from another machine on the network? Or are you trying to host the service on a server somewhere in the network and then hit it there?

Comment: I want the Client to run on my Raspberry Pi , and I want that this client invoke specific method from the Server while Server is located on my Computer.Both devices have dhcp address .

Answer (score 4):

All you need is to publish Web Service. On order to publish you should right click on the project in the solution explorer, then select publish. Then Create new virtual directory in IIS Manager that points the publish folder. I'm not whure which system and IIS versions do you have, anyway [here](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/48/posts/10055/walkthrough-on-creating-wcf-40-service-and-hosting-in-iis-75.aspx) is the guide.

Comment: Unfortunately , it doesnt answer my question

Comment: Same thing for all web projects

Comment: Thanks for your help ,heq, it helped me to find the correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

OK , I have managed to solve the problem. 
First of all before dealing with IIS ,verify this :[that you configured it well](http://www.netomatix.com/Development/IIS7_404Error.aspx)

It took me hours browsing through forums to find this issue. 
Afterwards ,create new Site at your IIS ,if you intend to use it from remote places then
give it hostname like: `http://192.168.1.21` .
Add [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028010/the-test-form-is-only-available-for-requests-from-the-local-machine) to your Web.config file (only for remote sessions).

Then Go to your VS 2010 Web Server project (open VS as administrator),
Go to Propertirs --> Use local IIS --> Enter URL (In my case  `http://192.168.1.21/18.RaspPI_WEBSERVICE`) --> push Create Virtual Directory.

After those actions new directory should appear under your Site (my Site hostname was 192.168.1.21 ).

Press **Start** under Manage Web Site Panel and that basically it ...

I have managed to run Web service client on remote Raspberry PI and upload the gathered information into my Web Server over the IIS .